# MultiDatepicker addClass on hover dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I am using [Multidatepicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) for a project where I have two input type radio buttons which on change will pick up the value and select the array of dates according to the checked values.

So My code is :

```
$(function(){
$('#daterangePick').multiDatesPicker();
 $('.form-inputs input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
 var dayVal = $('.form-inputs input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
  $('#daterangePick').multiDatesPicker({
  mode: 'daysRange',
    autoselectRange: [0,dayVal],
  });
 });
 }());
```

My Html is:

```
<div class="form-inputs">
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="da[]" ><label>2 Days</label>
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="da[]" ><label>4 Days</label>
</div>
<div class="box" >
    <input type="text" id="daterangePick">
</div>
```

Now according to the project requirement I have to hover change color on hover the dates according to the checked values of my radio buttons.
But I am unable to hover i.e. adding a Class to by the length of dates from radio checked values.
Actually Client wants like this page feature https://www.renttherunway.com/shop/designers/elliatt/porcelain_picnic_dress

on the calendar dropdown

I would be highly obliged if anybody can help me to sort this out.

I have already done in this HTML 
http://lab-4.sketchdemos.com/HTML/datepickerTest/datepicker2/

I have made the select of dates on change of input fields
But I need to hover days as per the values of the input boxes on change function, which means if I check 2 days then 2days in the datepicker will hover and if I check 4 days then 4days in the datepicker will hover.

Please help me

Comment: "But I am unable to hover..." what does this mean? You can't add the css class, or you don't know how to make the css class, or...?

Comment: No I want to limit the hover date cells as per the values picked from onchange of input type radio buttons value. It means You can see there are 2 values in radio buttons, one is 2 days and other is 4 days, so when I click 2days the datepicker date cells will hover 2 cells and if it is 4 days the same will hover for 4 days, so I need to addClass according to the changed values of the input type radio fields